# Inner element overlap a parent sibling

Tags: css

I have a div that contains an ul and some li. The li are styled to display them as a list. In the left of the wrapping div there is a floating div.

I can't understand why the li can overlap the floating div, I checked the display, border-box property and so on, but I have no clues.

Screen:

[image]

```css
div.myDropdown {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 13px;
 zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
}
div.myDropdown * {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;  
}
div.myDropdown  div.mySelect {
 width: 100%;
 height: 24px;
 border: 1px solid #4195fc;
 border-radius: 6px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #4195fc; 
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 height: 100% !important;
}


div.myDropdown>a div.myArrow {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
 right: 0;
 display: block;
 width: 18px;
 height: 100%;
}
div.myDropdown>a div.myArrow.myArrowDown::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f078";
    font-size: 17px;
 color: #999;
}
div.myDropdown  ul.mySelection {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
}
div.myDropdown  div.mySelect ul.mySelection>li {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #4195fc;
 margin: 2px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-right: 2px;
}
div.myDropdown  div.mySelect ul.mySelection>li>span.myDeselect::before {
 font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00d";
    font-size: 10px;
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDropdown" style="width: 296px;"><a><div class="mySelect myMultiple"><span class="myValue" style="display: none;"></span><div class="myArrow myArrowDown"></div><ul class="mySelection"><li data-val="CL">Chile<span class="myDeselect"></span></li><li data-val="CN">China<span class="myDeselect"></span></li><li data-val="CX">Christmas Island<span class="myDeselect"></span></li><li data-val="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands<span class="myDeselect"></span></li><li data-val="CG">Congo<span class="myDeselect"></span></li><li data-val="CO">Colombia<span class="myDeselect"></span></li></ul></div></a></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/aoro5pas/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you `.myArrow` div is positioned absolute with a width of `18px`.  You `ul` has a width of 100% so it doesn't account for these `18px`.  You could do

```
div.myDropdown ul.mySelection {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 18px); /*Reduce the ul width by 18px so avoid overlapping*/
}
```

Or another solution is to add margin or padding to your `ul`

```
div.myDropdown ul.mySelection {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    /*Add either of these 2 */
    padding: 0 18px 0 0;
    margin: 0 18px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Totally missed it, sometimes two fresh eyes are needed :-)

Answer (score 2):

I presume the div you are talking about is '#myArrow'? This div is styled with position:absolute which means other components will overlap it. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

I would put

```
padding-right: 20px;
```

on the container div to prevent overlapping

Answer (score 0):

Browser defaults could be an issue here as well.

For consistent cross browser results it wouldn't hurt to start with a browser CSS reset. Using normalize.css with your HTML and CSS code unchanged, here's what I get:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/2xs1u941/1/

Easy to check, add the following to your head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css">
```

[Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)